# ComboBox selectionModel error

Tags: combobox, javafx

I'm trying to clear selection model for my comboBox, but im getting an error. Maybe it is not how i should clear it? (i want to reset choice then something was chosen).

I checked the code and selection model part gives me an error. The thing is i used this method in my other project and it worked fine.

Code

```
private void handleGenreBox(ActionEvent event) {
    if (genreField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        genreField.setText(genreBox.getValue().toString()); 
    }
    else if (!genreField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        genreField.appendText(", " + genreBox.getValue().toString());
    }
    genreBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
}
```

And here is the error.

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:256)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$$Lambda$149/1082354338.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:150)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.updateValue(ComboBox.java:471)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.access$300(ComboBox.java:187)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$4.changed(ComboBox.java:454)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel.lambda$new$154(ComboBox.java:502)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel$$Lambda$291/646998814.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
    at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(SingleSelectionModel.java:215)
    at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.clearSelection(SingleSelectionModel.java:68)
    at TvSeriesControllers.AddTvSeriesController.handleGenreBox(AddTvSeriesController.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:256)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$$Lambda$149/1082354338.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:150)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.updateValue(ComboBox.java:471)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.access$300(ComboBox.java:187)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$4.changed(ComboBox.java:454)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel.lambda$new$154(ComboBox.java:502)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel$$Lambda$291/646998814.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
    at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(SingleSelectionModel.java:215)
    at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.select(SingleSelectionModel.java:149)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.lambda$createListView$321(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:695)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$$Lambda$359/1775295764.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:395)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:348)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1400)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:260)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:224)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$235/1870621590.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    ... 155 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TvSeriesControllers.AddTvSeriesController.handleGenreBox(AddTvSeriesController.java:63)
    ... 165 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:136)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:242)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$178(ListViewBehavior.java:266)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior$$Lambda$371/1518324523.onChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:75)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:370)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1400)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:260)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:224)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$235/1870621590.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The StackTrace says its a NPE. What line of code do you have at `line 63` of AddTvSeriesController.java?

Comment: The line is genreField.appendText(", " + genreBox.getValue().toString());

Comment: `genreField` cannot be null because you are using it in the condition. So either `genreBox` is null or `genreBox.getVaue()` is.

Comment: While it is not a big deal, i would love to know how to fix this kind of issues ? I just ran out of options i could think of.

Comment: If you try and call a method on a reference which is null, you will get a NPE. You can always avoid NPE by checking whether a reference is null or not, before using it.